# How to Ignore AnyPublisher output in swift combine (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I have a function (which does some network calls like toggling a flag on the server) which returns `AnyPublisher<a,b>`

```
func functionWhichReturnsAnyPublisher() -> AnyPublisher<a,b> {
}
```

In one of the cases, I do not use the output of it.

Is there any alternative without using the sink on it as I am not using any of the output from the call?

If I do not call sink it is not performing the network operation.

```
functionWhichReturnsAnyPublisher().sink {_ in } receiveValue: { _ in

}.store(in: &subscriptions)
```

Answer (score 3):

You must attach a subscriber to a publisher, otherwise the publisher will not start.

You can use [`ignoreOutput`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/fail/ignoreoutput()) to ignore the output of a publisher.

```
functionWhichReturnsAnyPublisher().ignoreOutput().store(in: &subscriptions)
```

You might want to consider still using `sink` so that you can handle any errors that result from the publisher.

Comment: It doesn't work and shouldn't work because `ignoreOutput` returns `Publisher` and `sink` returns `Subscriber`. `store(in:)` works with subscribers only.